# Union Query pulling data differently then corresponding select query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016, union-all

Union query is sometimes pulling the Record Number of the related description field instead of the description itself. This is supposed to Union Foil Number 1-4 and Foil Color 1-4 into a single field each.

[image: Record Number being pulled]

Here is the corresponding select query where it pulls in the proper description, instead of record number.

[image: Correct Descriptions]

Those numbers correspond exactly with the record number of CASHMERE LIGHT and COASTLINE GREY in my MasterFoilList (Table all of the Foils are stored in).

I was wondering if anyone has had this problem or a similar one, as when I run the select statements from the Union individually it pulls the information in correctly. But adding them to the Union only seems to mess with my second select statement. I will post the SQL below, but be warned it is a bit large with all of the criteria required.

```
SELECT Qry_ScheduledItems.Sales_Order_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Customer_Name, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Ship_To_Location, Qry_ScheduledItems.Part_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Quantity_Ordered, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Due, Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number1 AS Foil_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color1 AS 
Foil_Color, Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Slit1 AS Foil_Slit, Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_SQFTG1 AS Foil_SQFTG, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.[Wrap/Foil_Notes], Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation1, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled1, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran1, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation2, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled2, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran2, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation3, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled3, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran3, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation4, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled4, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran4, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation5, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled5, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran5, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation6, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled6, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran6, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation7, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled7, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran7, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation8, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled8, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran8, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation9, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled9, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran9, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation10, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled10, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran10, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation11, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled11, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran11, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation12, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled12, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran12, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation13, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled13, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran13, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation14, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled14, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran14, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped 

FROM Qry_ScheduledItems 

WHERE (((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number1) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color1) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation1) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation1)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran1) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number1) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color1) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation2) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation2)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran2) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number1) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color1) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation3) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation3)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran3) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number1) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color1) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation4) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation4)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran4) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number1) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color1) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation5) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation5)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran5) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number1) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color1) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation6) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation6)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran6) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number1) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color1) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation7) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation7)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran7) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number1) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color1) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation8) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation8)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran8) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number1) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color1) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation9) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation9)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran9) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number1) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color1) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation10) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation10)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran10) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number1) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color1) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation11) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation11)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran11) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number1) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color1) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation12) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation12)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran12) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number1) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color1) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation13) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation13)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran13) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number1) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color1) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation14) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation14)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran14) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) 

UNION ALL SELECT Qry_ScheduledItems.Sales_Order_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Customer_Name, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Ship_To_Location, Qry_ScheduledItems.Part_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Quantity_Ordered, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Due, Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number2 AS Foil_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color2 AS 
Foil_Color, Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Slit2 AS Foil_Slit, Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_SQFTG2 AS Foil_SQFTG, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.[Wrap/Foil_Notes], Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation1, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled1, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran1, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation2, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled2, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran2, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation3, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled3, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran3, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation4, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled4, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran4, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation5, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled5, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran5, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation6, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled6, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran6, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation7, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled7, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran7, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation8, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled8, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran8, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation9, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled9, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran9, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation10, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled10, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran10, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation11, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled11, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran11, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation12, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled12, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran12, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation13, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled13, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran13, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation14, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled14, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran14, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped 

FROM Qry_ScheduledItems 

WHERE (((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number2) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color2) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation1) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation1)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran1) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number2) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color2) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation2) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation2)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran2) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number2) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color2) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation3) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation3)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran3) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number2) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color2) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation4) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation4)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran4) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number2) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color2) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation5) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation5)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran5) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number2) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color2) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation6) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation6)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran6) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number2) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color2) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation7) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation7)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran7) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number2) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color2) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation8) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation8)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran8) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number2) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color2) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation9) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation9)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran9) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number2) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color2) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation10) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation10)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran10) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number2) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color2) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation11) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation11)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran11) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number2) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color2) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation12) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation12)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran12) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number2) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color2) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation13) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation13)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran13) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number2) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color2) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation14) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation14)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran14) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) 

UNION ALL SELECT Qry_ScheduledItems.Sales_Order_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Customer_Name, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Ship_To_Location, Qry_ScheduledItems.Part_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Quantity_Ordered, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Due, Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number3 AS Foil_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color3 AS 
Foil_Color, Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Slit3 AS Foil_Slit, Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_SQFTG3 AS Foil_SQFTG, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.[Wrap/Foil_Notes], Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation1, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled1, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran1, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation2, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled2, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran2, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation3, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled3, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran3, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation4, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled4, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran4, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation5, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled5, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran5, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation6, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled6, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran6, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation7, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled7, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran7, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation8, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled8, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran8, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation9, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled9, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran9, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation10, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled10, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran10, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation11, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled11, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran11, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation12, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled12, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran12, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation13, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled13, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran13, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation14, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled14, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran14, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped 

FROM Qry_ScheduledItems 

WHERE (((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number3) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color3) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation1) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation1)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran1) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number3) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color3) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation2) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation2)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran2) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number3) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color3) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation3) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation3)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran3) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number3) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color3) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation4) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation4)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran4) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number3) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color3) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation5) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation5)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran5) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number3) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color3) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation6) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation6)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran6) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number3) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color3) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation7) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation7)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran7) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number3) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color3) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation8) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation8)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran8) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number3) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color3) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation9) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation9)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran9) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number3) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color3) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation10) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation10)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran10) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number3) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color3) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation11) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation11)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran11) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number3) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color3) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation12) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation12)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran12) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number3) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color3) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation13) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation13)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran13) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number3) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color3) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation14) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation14)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran14) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) 

UNION ALL SELECT Qry_ScheduledItems.Sales_Order_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Customer_Name, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Ship_To_Location, Qry_ScheduledItems.Part_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Quantity_Ordered, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Due, Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number4 AS Foil_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color4 AS 
Foil_Color, Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Slit4 AS Foil_Slit, Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_SQFTG4 AS Foil_SQFTG, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.[Wrap/Foil_Notes], Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation1, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled1, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran1, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation2, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled2, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran2, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation3, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled3, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran3, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation4, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled4, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran4, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation5, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled5, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran5, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation6, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled6, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran6, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation7, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled7, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran7, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation8, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled8, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran8, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation9, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled9, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran9, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation10, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled10, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran10, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation11, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled11, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran11, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation12, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled12, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran12, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation13, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled13, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran13, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation14, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled14, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran14, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped 

FROM Qry_ScheduledItems 

WHERE (((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number4) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color4) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation1) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation1)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran1) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number4) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color4) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation2) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation2)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran2) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number4) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color4) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation3) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation3)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran3) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number4) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color4) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation4) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation4)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran4) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number4) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color4) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation5) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation5)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran5) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number4) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color4) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation6) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation6)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran6) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number4) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color4) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation7) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation7)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran7) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number4) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color4) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation8) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation8)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran8) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number4) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color4) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation9) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation9)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran9) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number4) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color4) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation10) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation10)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran10) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number4) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color4) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation11) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation11)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran11) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number4) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color4) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation12) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation12)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran12) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number4) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color4) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation13) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation13)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran13) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null)) OR (((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number4) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color4) Is Not Null) AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation14) Like "Foil" Or (Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation14)="Edge Foil") AND ((
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran14) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null));
```

Comment: So, if your 2nd query were reduced to its essentials, and forgetting for the moment the enormous WHERE clause, it would look like `SELECT Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Number2 AS Foil_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Foil_Color2 AS Foil_Color from Qry_ScheduledItems`?  Have I got that right?

Comment: How do you know Query 2 is the culprit?

Comment: @AnnL. Yes that would boil it down to what I am trying to Union. And I know the second query is the culprit because when I run all of the select statements individually those are the two records that are showing as "36" & "64". They aren't showing incorrectly in the original select statements, only when I add them to the Union. (Also of all the parts being queried here those are the only 2 with information in Foil Number 2 and Foil Color 2).

Comment: When something odd happens, I'd look at the underlying data, or query in this case.  If you run `Qry_ScheduledItems` and look at all the `Foil_Color` fields for F-4027, do you only see the correct value, or are there some numbers?

Comment: Is `Qry_ScheduleItems` a big monster of a query? Sometimes in Access, when you have lots of records joined in complicated ways, things just go wrong for no obvious reason. In that case, you need to simplify, even down to something like "use the last reliable query to make a table, and base the next query on that."  It's not pretty, but sometimes Access just get stretched past its limits.

Comment: @AnnL. I figured it out, likely when designing the tables I forgot to set the Bound Columns to the same number. Foil Color 1 had a bound column of 1 where as Foil Color 2, 3, & 4 all had it set to 0. I haven't seen Access insert the record number as opposed to the PK for an incorrect bound column, but your first suggestion of looking at the underlying queries tipped me off. Thanks!